# How do I create a 2D array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, p5.js, conways-game-of-life

I'm working on this assignment where I need to construct a version of The Game of Life. I'm having trouble getting this 2D array set up properly so that I can track whether or not cells are 'alive' or 'dead'. I've seem to have hit a wall and I need someone to just put me in the right direction.

```
var grid;

function setup () {
 createCanvas(400, 400);
 grid = new Grid(20);
}

function draw () {
 background(245);

   grid.draw();
}

class Grid {
  constructor (cellSize) {
   this.cellSize = cellSize;
   this.numberOfColumns = height/this.cellSize;
   this.numberOfRows = width/this.cellSize;

   this.cells = new Array(this.numberOfColumns);
   this.rows = new Array(this.numberOfRows);
   this.twoDArray = new Array(this.cells);

  for (var i = 0; i < this.cells; i++) {
   this.twoDArray[i] = new Array(this.rows);
  }


 // for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
  // for (var row = 0; row < this.numberOfRows; row++) {
   // this.cells[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, cellSize);
  //}
  // }

 print(this.cells);
}

draw() {
 for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
   for (var row = 0; row < this.numberOfRows; row++) {
     fill(240); 
     noStroke();
     rect(column * this.cellSize + 1, row * this.cellSize + 1, this.cellSize - 1, this.cellSize - 1);
    }
  }
 }
}
   class Cell {
    contructor (column, row, cellSize) {
     this.column = column;
     this.row = row;
     this.cellSize = cellSize;
     isAlive = false;
    }
  }
```

Whenever I try to uncomment the code I have commented above, the console says: TypeError: Cannot set property of '0' undefined. I'm certain I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to see what it is. Any help that you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to explicitly initialize each row to its own new array. The `Array()` constructor just gives you a single *empty* array.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use `this.cells` as a multi dimensional array, since it is populated with empty elements as per the `new Array` does.

You should change your code to something like:

```
for (var column = 0; column < this.numberOfColumns; column ++) {
  this.cells[column] = []; // or use here new Array or similar
  for (var row = 0; row < this.numberOfRows; row++) {
    this.cells[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, cellSize);
  }
}
```